# multiple paypal checkout button on 1 page

Tags: php, jquery, paypal

Im creating web application that allow user to pay amount of money via paypal. I use the modal style on button click. I put three button, with different amount for each button.
But I stumble upon using more than 1 paypal checkout button. when i trigger the first button, it the script run 3 times, how can i fix this? or this kind of thing cannot be done?

here my code snippet (3 paypal button):

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="portlet light bordered">
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight: bold">$10.00</span><br>
                            <p>Instantly Topup $10.00 into your balance.</p>
                            <div id="paypal-button1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="portlet light bordered">
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight: bold">$50.00</span><br>
                            <p>Instantly Topup $50.00 into your balance.</p>
                            <div id="paypal-button2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="portlet light bordered">
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight: bold">$100.00</span><br>
                            <p>Instantly Topup $100.00 into your balance.</p>
                            <div id="paypal-button3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

here my paypal script:

```
paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

        client: {
            sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxx',
            production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        },

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '10.00', currency: 'SGD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            // Execute the payment here
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

                // The payment is complete!
                var userid = $("#login_user").attr("data-id");
                var qty_1 = 10;
                var alert = $('<div class="alert alert-success">You successfully top-up your credits</div>');
                $("#paypal_info").before(alert);
                $(".alert").delay(2000).fadeOut(1500, function() {
                    alert.remove();

                    $('#elementBalance').empty();
                    //update total balance
                    updateBalance(userid, qty_1);

                    //reload total credit now
                    loadBalance(userid);

                    //reload history
                    //$('#paypal_info').empty();
                    //loadMembers(login_user_id);
                });
                // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
            });
       }

    }, '#paypal-button1');

    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

        client: {
            sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxx',
            production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        },

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function(data2, actions2) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '50.00', currency: 'SGD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data2, actions2) {
            // Execute the payment here
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

                // The payment is complete!
                var alert = $('<div class="alert alert-success">You successfully top-up your credits</div>');
                $("#paypal_info").before(alert);
                $(".alert").delay(2000).fadeOut(1500, function() {
                    alert.remove();
                    //reload total credit now
                    //$('#paypal_info').empty();
                    //loadMembers(login_user_id);
                });
                // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
            });
       }

    }, '#paypal-button2');

    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

        client: {
            sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxx',
            production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        },

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '100.00', currency: 'SGD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            // Execute the payment here
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

                // The payment is complete!
                var alert = $('<div class="alert alert-success">You successfully top-up your credits</div>');
                $("#paypal_info").before(alert);
                $(".alert").delay(2000).fadeOut(1500, function() {
                    alert.remove();
                    //reload total credit now
                    //$('#paypal_info').empty();
                    //loadMembers(login_user_id);
                });
                // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
            });
       }

    }, '#paypal-button3');
```

Comment: Make a common function and pass the amount to it. Don't write the code 3 times.

Comment: can you show me how is it done? im new to javascript and completely lost here.